# Socket triggered for each component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have a top component `App.js` and two children `hue.js` and `switch.js` (who are siblings).

In `App.js`, I create the socket like this :

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.0.26:4000');

socket.once("connect", () =>{
  socket.emit('authenticate', {token: 'test'});
  socket.once('authenticated', ()=>{
    console.log("Application connected !");
  });
});

export default class main extends Component {
  ...
}
```

Below, I call my `Hue` child like this :

```
<Hue propSocket = {socket}/>
```

And my `Switch` child like this :

```
<Switch propSocket = {socket}/>
```

As you can see, I'm passing the socket created on top-level so that I don't have multiple connections.

Here is the code of the `Hue` Component :

```
export default class Hue extends Component {
  state = {
    toggleState : false,
  }

  importedSocket = this.props.propSocket

  render() {    
    this.importedSocket.once('hue-state-change', (state)=>{
      console.log("Received "+state);
      this.setState({toggleState: state});
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

The code of switch.js is basically the same.

This is supposed to happen : when I run the app on two devices, if one user modify a value, the value is broadcasted to all the other clients.

When I run the app with only one child component, it works great. When I run the app with the two children components, I don't know how or why it looks like it is duplicating listeners because the `socket.once` event is triggered two times more every-time. Like 2 then 4, 8, 16...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is my server.js code in case it comes from here :

```
require('socket.io-auth')(io, auth, function(socket){


    socket.on('hue-state', (state) => {
      if (state == true) {console.log(socket.device+" turned the Hue ON.")}
      else {console.log(socket.device+" turned the Hue OFF.");}

      hue_state = state
      socket.broadcast.emit('hue-state-change', state);
      console.log("done");

    });

...
}
```

Comment: Why not listen within your top component ?

Comment: There are a lot of listeners, I don't want to pollute the main component. I also tried to export the listeners into one file named socket.js that would trigger the children components when an event was received but the same happened.